# Python Regex match group after first character occurrence

Tags: python, regex

First time working with Python Regex and I just need a little tip on matching strings.

I have a url like this: `url = "https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?xorp=True&xoaf=1&v=UloIw7dhnlQ&signature=C2AF3C2887A37043353A86AAAACFA796659B56CB.E736B7146447843F2D3311234744DC0D9937AF7B&asr_langs=fr%2Cru%2Ces%2Cnl%2Cit%2Cde%2Cko%2Cen%2Cpt%2Cja&sparams=asr_langs%2Ccaps%2Cv%2Cxoaf%2Cxorp%2Cexpire&expire=1541769991&key=yttt1hl=&encaps=asrlang=enfmt=srv3"`

I am trying to match everything except the part that begins with `expire=1541769991` (2nd to last line). This is what I have come up with:

`matchObj = re.match( r'(.*)expire=(.*)&(.*?)', url)`

The problem is the third group includes the text after the last occurrence of `&`. I want the text following the first occurrence of `&` after `expire=`. I tried adding a `?` after `&` to make it non-greedy too. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex,

```
matchObj = re.match( r"(.*)expire=[^&]*(&.*)", url)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import re

url = "https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?xorp=True&xoaf=1&v=UloIw7dhnlQ&signature=C2AF3C2887A37043353A86AAAACFA796659B56CB.E736B7146447843F2D3311234744DC0D9937AF7B&asr_langs=fr%2Cru%2Ces%2Cnl%2Cit%2Cde%2Cko%2Cen%2Cpt%2Cja&sparams=asr_langs%2Ccaps%2Cv%2Cxoaf%2Cxorp%2Cexpire&expire=1541769991&key=yttt1hl=&encaps=asrlang=enfmt=srv3"

match = re.match("(.+?)(expire=.+?&)(.+$)", url)
print(match.group(1) + match.group(3))
```

**Output**

```
https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?xorp=True&xoaf=1&v=UloIw7dhnlQ&signature=C2AF3C2887A37043353A86AAAACFA796659B56CB.E736B7146447843F2D3311234744DC0D9937AF7B&asr_langs=fr%2Cru%2Ces%2Cnl%2Cit%2Cde%2Cko%2Cen%2Cpt%2Cja&sparams=asr_langs%2Ccaps%2Cv%2Cxoaf%2Cxorp%2Cexpire&key=yttt1hl=&encaps=asrlang=enfmt=srv3
```

Or if you simply want the text without the `expire=`, you can remove it:

```
result = re.sub("expire=\d+?&", "", url)
```

Note that assumes that the value of expire are all digits.